# How do I extract the first tuple from a generated bag (whose size might vary) in PIG?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am generating a 'bag' of information whose size (number of tuples inside the the bag) might vary. From this, I want to extract the first element on the fly. How do I do this?

Comment: The first element of every tuple, or the first tuple?

Comment: Looking the answer and the 'tick' mark, its the first element of every tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html), a bag is a collection of tuples and

> Bag dereferencing can be done by name (bag.field_name) or position (bag.$0). If a set of fields are dereferenced (bag.(name1, name2) or bag.($0, $1)), the expression represents a bag composed of the specified fields.

But be careful, `b.$0` doesn't give you the first tuple in the bag, because bags aren't ordered!  You'll get the first elements of the constituent tuples.

You will need to either convert the bag to an ordered structure, or better, use a UDF.  You should also unaccept this answer (so I can delete it) and accept Guarev's instead, who has a link to a UDF.

Comment: In my case, "describe myBag" says: 
    myBag: {group: long,sorted::memberId: long,sorted::positionOrder: int,sorted::positionId: long,sorted::positionTitle: {(positionTitle: chararray)},sorted::positionCompany: {(positionCompany: chararray)}}

positionTitle and positionCompany are bags of tuples. How do I extract first tuples from both the bags?

flatten(positionTitle.$0) did not help. That brought all the values of positionTitle and crossed them with all the values of positionCompany.

Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: Bag dereferencing always means double dereferencing i.e. when you say b.$0 it does not dereference to first tuple (or element) of the bag, but instead dereference to first element inside the tuple. If you say `generate b.$0` it would create bag of tuples with only first elements from every tuples inside the bag.

Comment: I don't think this actually answer the question. In fact, I don't think the question has a solution since a bag implies no order at all.

Comment: I don't disagree that the mathematical concept of a bag is unordered, and the Pig Latin documentation itself simply says a bag is a collection of tuples, but the documentation also states, and I quote, "Bag dereferencing can be done by name (`bag.field_name`) or position (`bag.$0`)."  Whether or not you get anything reliable and repeatable from the expression `b.$0` is of course debatable, and I would never do this myself, but Pig does allow it!  That said, you have a good point, +1.

Answer (score 8):

Use DataFu UDF: FirstTupleFromBag (http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.2.0/datafu/pig/bags/FirstTupleFromBag.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the ordering of the tuple in the bag is important to get the "first" one (of course it is!) then you could do something like the following which is explained in more detail at https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/22863/cant-we-filter-the-data-which-we-have-done-in-37-s.html#answer-22995.

```
max_runs = FOREACH grp_data {
    inner_sorted = ORDER runs BY runs DESC;
    first_row = LIMIT inner_sorted 1;
    GENERATE first_row AS most_hits;
}
```