# Get distinct set of tuples in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, schema

I have the following relation:

```
DUMP A;
(Rick, m, 22, Mary, f, 23)
(Helen, f, 35, Mark, m, 37)
(Mary, f, 23, Rick, m, 22)
```

The sixplet tuples are basically two triplets and you can see that the first tuple and the last one contain the same information which is just flipped over. I need to eliminate these duplicates. So that the final result would look like:

```
DUMP A_distinct;
(Rick, m, 22, Mary, f, 23)
(Helen, f, 35, Mark, m, 37)
```

What would be a nice concise way to generate A_distinct out of A?
Thanks.

Comment: Where did John come from? Shouldn't the output be Rick m 22?Post your entire pig script and sample data from the file

Comment: @inquisitive_mind: yes, thanks for catching, I have fixed the question.

Comment: How do you factually know that the rick in the first row is the same rick in the third row?

Comment: @Andrew : You can assume that the triplet uniquely defines a user. So yes, it is the same Rick.

Answer (score -1):

One solution could be generate a Hash of all the values in a record and then run a distinct on it.

Pseudo code would look like this -

```
A = FOREACH A GENERATE A.$0,...A.$5, yourhashfunction(A.$0,...A.$5) as hash;
A = GROUP A by hash;
```

To retrieve the first tuple in every grouped BAG you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113964/how-do-i-extract-the-first-tuple-from-a-generated-bag-whose-size-might-vary-in).

Comment: Can someone explain why -1?